# datarangepicker con jquery o bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, datepicker, jquery-datepicker

Bueno comunidad, llevo varias horas tratando de conseguir las librerias de `daterangepicker` para insertar  esa funcion en mi página, y nada que he podido.

Esto son mis links en el head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
```

El script de la función:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();
});
</script>
```

Y en el index:

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="05/08/2017 - 05/08/2017" />
```

El problema es que ni siquiera se despliega la ventana de selección de fechas.
Agredeceria ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Usando exactamente tu código en un *fiddle* funciona bien: https://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/nhvs6x76/. Debe ser algo en tu entorno, ¿puedes darnos más detalles?

Comment: wow, 2 dias creyendo que era falta de alguna libreria o el codigo, haber , escribi el codigo en un direcorio fuera donde tengo guardada mi pagina y tambien me funciono bien, el problema es dentro de mi directorio, sera algun conflicto entre librerias?ya que tengo varias

Comment: Eso si es posible, si estás usando otras librerias pueden entrar en conflicto, ¿Quizá estás usando alguna otra version de jQuery?

Comment: Si era problema de mi entorno, actualice jquery a la version mas nueva, y quite la que tenia vieja en mi proyecto, y listo, thanks